# VIsual Studio Code error cannot open output file main.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

This is my first project with Visual Studio Code. When I go to run my "Hello World" project I get this

```
cd "c:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice\"main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file main.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code reads

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std:: cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

- I've made sure it isn't running in the background.
- I've closed and reopened the program and ran the code again with same results.
- I've allowed it as an exception in Bit Defender.

Comment: try to find it using cmd commend tasklist, and kill it using taskkill

Comment: looks like `collect2.exe` is locked by the OS. Google "Windows find locked file" or something. There are programs you can use which will tell you what files are using what files so you can end the proper task.

Comment: @Andy When I search n the Process Explorer when i search for `collect2.exe`  i get 0 matching results.

Comment: Don't use process explorer, use `LockHunter` -- it integrates into Windows Explorer. You just right-click on it and it will tell you what is locking it. If it comes up with nothing, manually delete the file and try again.

Comment: @Andy It is telling me that no processes locking this file or folder have been found. Would reinstalling the MinGW build I downloaded help any? I'm assuming that's what you're talking about when you say delete that specific file.

Comment: @Andy when I search MinGW in `LockHunter`  explorer.exe is locking the C:\MinGW folder

Comment: This part of your command doesn't look right `"c:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice"main` There's a backslash missing between Cpppractice and main.

Answer (score -1):

Try to open terminal (Ctrl + `) and type:
**g++ main.cpp**       then
**.\a.exe**

(assuming the terminal opens up in your working directory)

Comment: His existing command is calling `g++` properly and using the `-o` option correctly.

Comment: What I get back is                                                                                      PS C:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice> g++ main.cpp
PS C:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice> .\a.exe
Hello World!
PS C:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice>

Comment: I think your program ran correctly as it displayed "Hello World!" and PS C:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice> is added after hello world because you didn't specify new line. To get "Hello World!" without PS C:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice>   add std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; [notice the \n for new line]

Comment: cd "c:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice\" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "c:\Users\imaco\Desktop\Cpppractice\"main
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file main.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score -1):

I need 50 reputation to comment, otherwise I would have added a comment. I ran into this issue myself and I solved it using this. However, it worked for me:

"cannot open output file main.exe: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

It says that the permission has been denied. This probably means that you have not given execute access to visual studio in a certain folder or the file has execute restrictions. You could probably be storing this file in a folder that has restricted access. There are a couple of options:

- You could probably move it to a new folder that does not have any execute access restrictions.
- You may have have to change the permission of that folder/file to read, write and execute using admin privileges.

If this does not work, let me know in the comments section, because I faced the same issue of permission denied.

Comment: The OP is not using Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons for this error is that your firewall is blocking "collect2.exe" file. In some cases the firewall is disconnected so you might need to connect with it. Hope it helps !

Answer (score -2):

This usually happens when VS decides to keep a chunk of code running as a separate entity in the background. A way to fix this is that since you are on Windows, I would right-click the taskbar and click on task manager. This will open up all the tasks that are currently running on the computer. Then, search for "Windows console host." You can change the sorting of the list. Once you find it you can click on it and then at the bottom right it will have an "End Task" available for you to click. Click that and then retry again.

You should be good after that, but let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: When I open the task manager there  are no processes named `Windows Console Host`

Comment: Windows console host or the name of the program you made. This has happened to me a few times, so I would try to look in the task manager for any duplicate instances of the program that might be running. The program might be hung for some reason, which I can't see why it would but I would try checking for any sort of instances that might be linked to the program in task manager.

Comment: VSC had 5 processes running, but ending one closed the program entirely.

Answer (score -2):

when this occurs i usually just remove the exe file and build again